# the generator prime mover power

Tags: motor

I didn't understand why the text says:

Therefore the prime mover must be capable of supplying 175 kW

[image]

Reference: Electrical Machines, Drives, and Power Systems

Pearson Education Limited 2014, by Theodore Wildi

Comment: It looks wrong to me.

Comment: it's 870.4kW not 175kW

Comment: Obviously there was a breakdown in the proofreading of this text.  Yes, it's wrong.